# rdbms database terms for hierarchical filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, database, filter, rdbms

Our project is looking to build a large database, and I am seeking the terms, techniques, and/or technologies to research for our implementation. I doubt our project is anything new, but want to leverage the common practices out there (and not learn from scratch).

A contrived, but very applicable, example of our project is a hierarchy like this:

- There will exist a few Publishing Houses (order of 10, total)
- PublishingHouses will have Publishers (order of 100, total)
- Publishers will have Authors (order of 1000, total)
- And Authors will have Books (order of
  10000, total)
- There will be Readers, who will have a record/review of Books (order
  of 5M, total)

A common reporting item for our system will be for a Publisher or Author to log into the system and gather the reviews of Readers. The trick is, they must only be able to see the Readers associated with the Books they control.

**Our concern is that each query for a reporting action will have to    sift through 5M Reader reviews to know if they match the    PublishingHouse, Publisher, Author and/or Book in question.**

What are the terms, techniques and/or technologies best suited to solve this problem? Could you explain why that would apply to our problem-set? I have more research to do, but hopefully your experience and answers will point us in the right direction.

Thanks!

(Still need more info, but my current solution is some joining tables for PublishingHouses to Publishers, Publishers to Authors, Authors to Books and use cascading JOINs when finding the Readers to ensure I have the right set. I've heard talks about "Views" that might apply here as well).

Comment: Just found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database?rq=1) which might be very relevant. Would still appreciate your answers/comments.

Comment: Are you already familiar with any relevant technologies, such as SQL, or do you com from a non-technical point of view?

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE I am familiar with basic SQL to query and create tables. Background is software. My past experiences used a DB to basically maintain application state - so the application was the driver and the DB was not very consequential (we also abstracted SQL calls with Hibernate). It feels like this new system will be DB-driven, at least for this reporting piece, so needs some extra planning up front (especially before/if we slap an ORM on top!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a classic use-case for relational databases (MySQL, Oracle, etc). I wouldn't worry too much about having 5M rows, if the lookup columns are indexed (i.e. you use some additional disk space but get fast lookups) you will be able to search and join no problem.

If your 'order of' values are in the right ballpark, you are looking at something like 10,000,000,000 books, so this would be your main size issue. At a measly 1000 characters per review you are looking at 10TB of data for these alone. At that scale, it might be worth starting to look at 'Big Data' solutions such as Hadoop/Hbase. However, these are typically not optimised for fast lookup, and are more designed for batch-job analytics, so would need some tweaking for what you want.

Hope that helps!

Comment: By the way according to Google, there are approximately 130M books in the world today, so you can probably get away with a standard relational database (with a reasonably big amount of storage) and plenty of indexing ;-)

Comment: I updated the question to indicate the 'order of' values were total, not growing for each level. So 5M-10M rows isn't a big deal these days in terms of search speed, if the JOINs to filter are needed each time first?

Comment: Should be fine :-) The main caveats are: a) index columns that you filter by and join on and b) do exact matches (eg publisher = 'PublisherA') rather than lexical comparison (eg publisher LIKE '%A%') as this will be much much slower. Although obviously depends on load, if you have thousands of requests per second it may struggle!

Comment: Just occurred to me, another thing you could look at for reporting is standalone indexing libraries - check out Apache's Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), I have used it before for indexed searches on about 10M rows and it is lightning fast

Comment: Not wanting to abandon this question, I will choose it as the answer. We are far from a complete implementation, but this answer and comments helped focus our thought-process. Thanks!